# WinForms компиляция NuGet

Tags: c#, winforms, nuget

Для подключения к sql server  использовал готовый DataConnectionDialog из пакета
  [Microsoft Data Connection Dialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog).

Вроде сделал все как надо, но при компиляции вылетает исключение:

> **Дополнительные сведения:**
>
> Не удалось найти ресурсы, соответствующие
>   указанной культуре или нейтральной культуре.  Проверьте правильность
>   внедрения или связывания
>   "Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Resources.resources" со сборкой
>   "BandivanKatUser" во время компиляции, или убедитесь, что все
>   необходимые сопутствующие сборки полностью подписаны и могут быть
>   загружены.

Это код, где вылетает исключение:

```
public static DataProvider SqlCeDataProvider 
{
    get 
    {
        if (_sqlCeDataProvider == null) 
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> descriptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            descriptions.Add(SqlCeDataSource.Name, 
                Resources.DataProvider_SqlEverywhere_Description);

            Dictionary<string, Type> uiControls = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
            uiControls.Add(String.Empty, typeof(SqlCeConnectionUIControl));

            _sqlCeDataProvider = new DataProvider(
                "System.Data.SqlCeClient",
                Resources.DataProvider_SqlEverywhere,
                "SqlCeClient",
                Resources.DataProvider_SqlEverywhere_Description,
                typeof(System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection),
                descriptions,
                uiControls,
                typeof(SqlCeConnectionProperties));
        }
        return _sqlCeDataProvider;
    }
}
```

А именно вот на этой строке:

```
descriptions.Add(SqlCeDataSource.Name, Resources.DataProvider_SqlEverywhere_Description);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#r "Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI"
#r "Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog"

using Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI;

static private string GetConnectionString() {
    DataConnectionDialog dcd = new DataConnectionDialog();
    DataSource.AddStandardDataSources(dcd);
    return DataConnectionDialog.Show(dcd) == DialogResult.OK ? dcd.ConnectionString : null;
}

var f = new Form();
new Button() { Text="Connect", Parent = f }.Click += (s, e) => {
    var cs = GetConnectionString();
    // ...
};
f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Где вставить этот фрагмент кода?

Comment: new Button() { Parent=this }.Click.... добавьте в конструктор формы. И метод GetConnectionString добавьте перед конструктором формы.

Comment: а указанные сборки добавьте в Solution Explorer - References своего проекта

Comment: @Stack сборки у ТС и так добавлены. падает при попытке работать с ними, с ошибкой загрузки ресурсов