# Создать систему логина и пароля

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

У меня есть таблица с пользователями и их ролями (администратор и обычный пользователь), надо сделать окно входа логина и пароля.
Что получилось, ругается что не подключилось к базе данных.

```
try
{
    string login = lTb.Text.Trim();
    string password = pTb.Text.Trim();

    string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Users WHERE login=" + login + " AND password=" + password;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string connStr = @"Data Source=10.10.10.34;Initial Catalog=14IT-1-Domas;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dom_an;Password=***********";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());

    if (count == 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Error!", "User not found!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success!", "Hello!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        new Form1().Show();
    }
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка подключения базы данных", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: _`password = pTb.Text ... query = ... + password;`_ -- если не проверяете что попадает в password, то может получиться sql запрос с `; drop table`

Comment: чтобы не получить инъекцию используйте SQLParameter'ы и почитайте technet.microsoft: [Атака SQL Injection](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> надо сделать окно входа логина и пароля.

Есть готовый Microsoft Data Connection Dialog -- для подкючения к разным базам данных. Пример использования - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475987/196972).